# Evaluating an integral using change of variables

Tags: calculus

$$\iint 4xy-1dA$$ bounded by y-x²=0 , y-x²=-1 , y²-x=0, y²-x=1 in the 1st quadrant.

Setting u=y-x² and v=y²-x and after solving for the jacobian , dA= (1)/(4xy-1)
This cancels out in the integral. With -1≤u≤0 and 0≤v≤1 , after solving the integral I get 1 as an answer.

I don't understand what is the point of the question mentioning the first quadrant. Why do I need to know this to solve the problem ? How does it change my answer ?

Comment: Please attach a good plot of the desired intersection to your question. It will automatically answer your question.  The way your problem is defined, there will be two valid intersections - one in 1st quadrant, one in 2-4rd. Also, take care about limits of integration, I don't think they are trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given integral represents integration of the region A that is enclosed by the four given curves considering the first quadrant only.  Here is a sketch of the region:

[image]

The coordinates of the intersection points are approximately:  A(1,1),B(1.5,1.2),C(1.2,1.5),D(1.6,1.5).  When integrating along the x-axis, it requires 3 integrals to cover region A.

$A1 = \int_1^{1.2} {\int_{\sqrt x }^{{x^2}} {(4xy-1)dydx} }  = 0.144$

$A2 = \int_{1.2}^{1.5} {\int_{\sqrt x }^{\sqrt {x + 1} } {(4xy-1)dydx} }  = 0.699$

$A3 = \int_{1.5}^{1.6} {\int_{{x^2} - 1}^{\sqrt {x + 1} } {(4xy-1)dydx} }  = 0.157$

It follows that the given integral equals approximately 1.

Comment: Ok now it makes more sense ! Thank you !

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry that I forgot the -1 in the first attempt.